# Bad cpu clocking LM3S6965 configuration

Tags: embedded

I just bought TI's LM3S6965 evaluation kit and try to play with it a little bit.
I checked with SysCtlClockGet() what is the cpu clock and figure out that it runs with 8MHZ.
then I tried to change the cpu clock to 50 MHZ:

```
#include <inc/hw_types.h>
#include <inc/hw_memmap.h>
#include <driverlib/sysctl.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
 SysCtlClockSet(SYSCTL_OSC_MAIN | SYSCTL_SYSDIV_4 | SYSCTL_USE_PLL | SYSCTL_XTAL_1MHZ);
 unsigned long clk = SysCtlClockGet()/1000000;
}
```

I debug it after the first line that sets the cpu clock it shows me the next error message:

```
CORTEX_M3_0: Error connecting to the target: LMI device check failed, bad part number detected.
```

i tried to reconnect it, reset it, programming the flash but it still show me this message.
what should i do? does the traget gone?

thanks for help :)

Comment: Did you power up, configure, and enable the PLL?  You usually have to do that before you can set the PLL as your clock source.  You may also have to wait until some status register indicates that the PLL is locked.  On some processors, switching clock sources may even have to be done with a specific series of assembly instructions.

Answer (score 0):

I have set CPU Clock to 8MHz and used PLL to reconfigure it. Here is the starting code

```
SysCtlClockSet(SYSCTL_SYSDIV_4 | SYSCTL_USE_PLL | SYSCTL_OSC_MAIN |SYSCTL_XTAL_8MHZ);
```

I have not tried it to 50MHz, but I don't think that should be a problem.